# What are gulp task async run hints?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I've got two tasks.

Sass:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('src/sass/**.{scss, sass}')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
            .on('error', handleErrors)
            .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});
```

And CSS optimization task:

```
gulp.task('cssopt', ['sass'], function() {
    gulp.src('dist/css/style.css')
        .pipe(uncss({html: ['http://example.dev//']}))
        .pipe(cmq({log: true}))
        .pipe(shrink())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.opt'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

The `cssopt` task relies on the `sass` task, cause it's using the `style.css` file that the `sass` generates. But it won't work, it can't find the `style.css` file, cause it's not there. If I run the `sass` separately first, then the `cssopt` works cause the `style.css` is there.

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> An array of tasks to be executed and completed ***before*** your task will run.

Docs also say:

> Note: Are your tasks running before the dependencies are complete? Make sure your dependency tasks are correctly using the async run hints: take in a callback or return a promise or event stream.

Which I don't quite understand: "async run hints"... wat...

I tried to run a `clean` task as `deps` for sass and that worked well, though.

---

I could smash these into one task, but the `cssopt` takes quite long (the `uncss` is pretty slow when you give it an URL), and I need the `style.opt.css` file only on production anyway.

I am using the latest version (1.3.3) of gulp-sass.

Comment: Async run hints in your case -> `return gulp.src(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "async run hints"... wat...

You need to *hint* the gulp system that your task is *async*. You can do that by taking a callback argument to your task function, or by `return`ing an event stream or promise. That's what your tasks are lacking, they return `undefined` currently so gulp expects them to have finished immediately. Try

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/**.{scss, sass}').…
```